# GSA limit reached with "noindex"

Tags: google-search-appliance

Recently the GSA I manage reached the limit in URLs being indexed and for what I see the total number of URLs with actual content is very low as opposed to the amount of page listings (mostly by date and that are not content but only show results for users to navigate).

I have already added the Robots meta tag with "noindex" attribute and many of the URLs show as "Excluded":
[image]

So I assume those documents are not being counted towards the licensed total but without that amount my crawled URLs cannot possibly reach the limit of 500K.

My other guess is that having multiple collections will make documents count towards the total even if sometimes documents are duplicate in a couple of collections.

Has somebody else faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving a warning that you have exceeded your index?  There is a limit of how many URLs, over your license, the GSA will crawl, but you should be able to have about 1M docs in your license (between CRAWLED/ERRORS/EXCLUDED).  Only 500K can be in the "Crawled URLs".

Comment: Yes, the warning is: "Number of URLs matching patterns exceeds the current license limit. Documents will start to be expunged from the index once the total number of indexed URLs (Total Documents Being Served" number in Content Sources > Diagnostics > Crawl Status page) also exceeds license limit. Please either install a larger license to allow indexing of more documents or trim down the patterns to reduce number of indexed documents." in red everytime I access the GSA console.

Comment: The clue is in the message:
"Documents will start to be expunged from the index *once the total number of indexed URLs  also exceeds license limit*"
You have nothing to worry about until that value approaches your license limit and can safely ignore the warning that you are seeing until then.